# In laravel based on the dropdown list selected value make the check box as read only field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have ui that contains dropdown list and check box.Based on the drop downlist selection value i want compare with the isnesd field(it is one more field in the database),based on that comparison i want to make check box as read only field.

**view:**

```
    <!-- Asset Type -->
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('asset_type_id') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="asset_type_id" class="col-md-3 control-label">@lang('admin/assetdetails/form.type')</label>
             <div class="controls col-md-7">
             <div class="field-box">
                    {{ Form::select('asset_type_id',$assettype_list, Input::old('asset_type_id'), array('class'=>'select2', 'onchange' => 'check(this.value)' ,'style'=>'width:350px')) }}
                    {{ $errors->first('asset_type_id', '<span class="alert-msg"><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i> :message</span>') }}
              </div>
              </div>
</div>

    <!-- NESD -->
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('nesd') ? 'error' : '' }}">
         <label for="nesd" class="col-md-3 control-label">@lang('admin/assetdetails/form.nesd')</label>
             <div class="controls col-md-7">
                 <input class="col-md-1 controls isnesdbox" type="checkbox" name="nesd"  id="nesd" value="1" {{ $assetdetail->nesd === '1' ? 'checked' : '' }} />
                {{ $errors->first('nesd', '<span class="alert-msg"><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i> :message</span>') }}
             </div>
</div>
```

**controller:**

```
public function getCreate()
    {
        $location_list = array('' => '') + Location::lists('name', 'id');

        $assettype_list = array('' => '') + Assettype::lists('asset_type', 'id');               

        // Show the page
        $assetdetail_options = array('0' => 'Top Level') + Assetdetail::lists('asset_number','id');

        return View::make('backend/assetdetails/edit')->with('assetdetail_options',$assetdetail_options)->with('assetdetail',new Assetdetail)->with('location_list',$location_list)->with('assettype_list',$assettype_list);
    }
```

Comment: You can't make a checkbox read-only based on what item you click in a select list using laravel or php. You need javascript to do that. On the other hand, i may have misinterpreted what you really need, please be more specific.

Comment: If i used javascript function means i need to get id and isnesd fields(as mentioned above)from database based on the drop downlist selection value.how can i get that 2 fields from database to view page based on dropdownlist value?