# getting selected value from drop down list in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel, in the view page I'm showing a Dropdown-List which is fetched from the database and based on that Dropdown-List value selection, I'm getting the corresponding value id. But I also want one more corresponding fields from database based on the Dropdown-List I'm selecting.
How to get it? Based on that values I want to do Javascript operation.

**Here's my code:**

```
{{ 
    Form::select('asset_type_id',$assettype_list, Input::old('asset_type_id'), 
    array('class'=>'select2', 'onchange' => 'check(Input::get(this.value);)',
    'style'=>'width:350px')) 
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `Input::get(this.value)` in your onchange as it will be printed literally. You can just use the code without the `Input::get`. Of course, this all depends on how you are using the value in your javascript.

```
{{ 
    Form::select('asset_type_id',$assettype_list, Input::old('asset_type_id'), 
    array('class'=>'select2', 'onchange' => 'check(this.value)',
    'style'=>'width:350px')) 
}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,i changed it to this.value it working fine(i am getting dropd down list value id) but my problem is along with that id i want to get one more fields based on that id.how to get it?can you help me..

Comment: You will have to show your javascript for this because I don't realy understand what you are asking. If this is another question, it is best to close this question and create a new one.

Comment: here is the link,about my final requirement:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26403916/in-laravel-based-on-the-dropdown-list-selected-value-make-the-check-box-as-read]